# Align all types of html input

Tags: html, css, input, alignment

I am currently trying to finish up a little exercise I did. I am trying to align both my text input and my select input boxes, but I can't seem to figure out how to align the select list to the input box. I have tried using labels and css, and tables, but somehow my forms end up scattered across each other. Any help is greatly appreciated:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Game Intro</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/webtech/sample.css"
</head>
<body>
<h1>Character Creation</h1>
<h2>You have 10 Gold Pieces</h2>
<ul>
    <li>1 gold piece buys 10 health tokens</li>
    <li>1 gold piece buys 2 experience tokens</li>
    <li>1 gold piece buys 10 supply tokens</li>
</ul>
<form action="gameIntro.php" method="post">
    <table>
    <p>Enter your character's name:
    <input type="text" size="20" name="character_name" /></p>
    <p>Select your character class:
    <select name="character_class">
        <option>Dwarf</option>
        <option>Human</option>
        <option>Elf</option>
        <option>Wizard</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    <p>Purchase health tokens:
    <select name="health_token">
        <option>0</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>30</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    <p>Purchase experience tokens:
    <select name="experience_token">
        <option>0</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>10</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    <p>Purchase supply tokens:
    <select name="supply_token">
        <option>0</option>
        <option>25</option>
        <option>50</option>
        <option>75</option>
        <option>100</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit your Character" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset your Character" /></p>
    </table>
    </form>
    <a href={"http://localhost/index.html"}>Go back to Homepage</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

css file:

```
body { background: white }
h1 { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
     font-size: 18pt; color: black; font-weight: bold; }
h2 { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
     font-size: 16pt; color: black; font-weight: bold; }
p { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 12pt; color: black; font-weight: bold; }
p.alert { font-style: italic; color: red; }
table { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 12pt; color: black; }
td.center { text-align: center; }
select { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
         font-size: 10pt; font-weight:  bold; color: blue;
         background: lightBlue; }
option { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
         font-size: 10pt; color: black; background: silver; }
```

Thx guys!

Comment: First off, You don't need to write those css rules over and over again. You can just put the font family on the `body { font-family: arial }` and it will "Cascade" down the "Style" "Sheet" ---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you learn to use a table properly. Tables are not stand alone elements, there are certain required child elements. for example

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Start with reviewing how tables work, and you'll find this much easier.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table   I wouldn't use a table for anything but "tabular data"

Comment: @sheriffderek Agreed.  I think table should be eliminated entirely and the stylesheet should be modified to fix the layout.  The styles are only defining fonts right now - nothing with layout.  That's (mainly) why his form looks like a mess.

Comment: @sheriffderek, A form is a perfect example of tabular data. But, even if you disagree, aligning a form without a table is overly complicated, and a table is still the best, easiest, simplest solution.

Comment: I have spent a lot of time designing responsive forms, and I can't say that a table is easiest... but I see you point on the data standpoint.

Comment: I like to mark forms up as lists... It's a list of input fields.  Not a table of attributes.

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly! I was confusing tr and td! Such a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

Use this HTML structure: Put your label/p elements on first column, `input` and `select` elements on second column.

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JRqS4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge - at this date... this is how I would mark up this form.
I only put the id's and for="" on the first input. I hope this helps you understand a bit better. Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/JGm8w/) - (change the browser window to see how the form adjusts for screen sizes)

### HTML

```
<form action="gameIntro.php" method="post" class="character-form">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="input-name">Enter your character's name:</label>
            <input id="input-name" type="text" size="20" name="character_name" />
        </li>

        <li>
            <label>Select your character class:</label>
            <select name="character_class">
                <option>Dwarf</option>
                <option>Human</option>
                <option>Elf</option>
                <option>Wizard</option>
            </select>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label>Purchase health tokens:</label>
            <select name="health_token">
                <option>0</option>
                <option>10</option>
                <option>20</option>
                <option>30</option>
            </select>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label>Purchase experience tokens:</label>
            <select name="experience_token">
                <option>0</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>6</option>
                <option>8</option>
                <option>10</option>
            </select>
       </li>

        <li>
            <label>Purchase supply tokens:</label>
            <select name="supply_token">
                <option>0</option>
                <option>25</option>
                <option>50</option>
                <option>75</option>
                <option>100</option>
            </select>
        </li>

    </ul>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit your Character" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset your Character" />

</form>
```

### CSS

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* look it up */
}

.character-form {
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden; /* should be a clearfix */
}

.character-form ul {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

.character-form li {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.character-form li label {
    border: 1px solid orange;
}

.character-form li input, .character-form li select {
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    float: left;
}

@media (min-width:20em) {

    .character-form {
        max-width: 30em;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }    

    .character-form li label {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: inline-block;
        min-width: 15em;
    }

    .character-form li input, .character-form li select {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .character-form li input {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 20em;
    }

    .character-form li select {
        min-width: 12em;
    }

} /* end break-point */
```